How to change border thickness/color of Entry in .NET MAUI Windows Platform when hovered/clicked?
When using custom EntryHandler and setting the border thickness to 1 and brush to red (following example).
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("Borderless", (handler, view) =>
            {
                if (view is Entry)
                {
#if WINDOWS
                    handler.PlatformView.BorderThickness = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Thickness(1);
                    handler.PlatformView.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red.ToWindowsColor());
#endif
                }

            });

It works unless I hover over it or click it... how can I apply the red border even when it's hovered/clicked?
I tried editing the event handlers for focus (following example).
textBox.GotFocus += (sender, args) => UpdateBorderColor(textBox);
textBox.LostFocus += (sender, args) => UpdateBorderColor(textBox);

this didn't work.
And I also tried setting the Entry border thickness to 0 globally, but it still reverts to normal when clicked/hovered (following example).
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

this also didn't work.

Why don't you just put your borderless Entry inside a Border or a Frame?

You can try the following code:
Add this on the App.xaml in Platforms/Windows:
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

Then put Entry into Border and set VisualState:
<Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 50">
   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
       <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
           <VisualState Name="Normal">
               <VisualState.Setters>
                   <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
                   <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Gray" />
               </VisualState.Setters>
           </VisualState>
           <VisualState Name="PointerOver">
               <VisualState.Setters>
                   <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="4" />
                   <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
               </VisualState.Setters>
           </VisualState>
       </VisualStateGroup>
   </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

   <Entry Placeholder="Input something" />
</Border>

